# How to add early stopping in Detectron2 model

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, detectron

I am using detectron2 for object detection, but facing over fitting issues.
Read somewhere of using after_step() function.. But can't understand how to fit the logic in the model...

Please help.

Thanks in advance.